# How to add cleanup code in spec file

Tags: pyinstaller

```
a = Analysis(['geoip.py', 'dbutils/geoipdb.py', 'dbutils/DBClass.py', 'commonutils.py', 'logutils.py'],
             pathex=['/opt/blu/app/master'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='geoip',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

The above code is my spec file. My task is to write cleanup code(ie..,to clear the files that are created when pyinstaller is executed like folder in build path and executable in dist path and also temp files) in spec file.

I know there is a clean option in pyinstaller and can be achieved by the following code:

```
pyinstaller --clean geoip.spec
```

But where can I write code for clean?

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete the build and dist folders created by pyinstaller?

Comment: yes. But after analyzing I came to know that the above command will actually delete build and dist also will create new build and dist automatically